# List Datasheet upload & added column

Tags: list, datasheet

This is hard to explain, but I'll do my best.

1. I have a SP list where I update the data from an excel file and copy&paste it into the datasheet view of my SP list.
2. I have a SP custom view of this list that only shows a handful of the columns available.
3. I then have added 2 columns of additional data to each entry in this SP list.

Question: To maintain my data I regularly have to copy&paste the excel data as in step 1. If rows are added/removed, will the data in the columns from step 3 still retain their association to the correct data? And if not is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, and I can't think of a way to do this in datasheet view. It would be easy enough to do programmatically, as long as you can uniquely pair rows in the spreadsheet to rows in the list (i.e. some column value, or combination of column values, will be unique).